# Efficient way to parallelize/speed up pandas groupby transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, time-series

I'm trying to speedup some code used to compute lags on pandas time indexed dataframes.
The dataframe contains ~200k timeseries identified by an ID column.
I tried dask but got no improvements (takes longer than pandas alone).

Here's a working example to generate a dummy dataframe with comparable size:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)

#Series for ID
ID_data = pd.Series(np.arange(0,200000), name='ID')

#Array of data - create pandas dataframe with datetime index
value_data = np.random.rand(52,1)
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=len(value_data), freq='D')
#Cross join with ID to create test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(value_data, columns=['value'], index=tidx).reset_index().merge(ID_data,how="cross").set_index('index')
```

Now, i want to compute a lag on value column ( 1 day lag in this example), for each timeseries (identified by ID column) :

```
%%time
df["value_lag1"] = df.groupby(['ID'])["value"].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1))
```

This code takes 30seconds to execute. Do you know any efficient way to speed it up ?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: The example script gave me: pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on.

Comment: Hi, i've got the following pandas/numpy version : ```print(pd.__version__) -> 1.3.1
print(np.__version__) -> 1.19.5```

Comment: i made a test on a blank notebook on my laptop and it's ok (with same pandas version)

Comment: Looks like mine are a bit older (1.0.5 and 1.18.4). I'll update and try again.

Comment: Updated and the test script works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the execution time without using lambda function with `.transform`.  Just use the [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) function directly for the GroupBy object, as follows:

```
df["value_lag1"] = df.groupby(['ID'])["value"].shift(1)
```

The execution time of the original version vs this version in my machine are **36.6s vs 0.715s**.  Improved by **51x times faster**.

With the lambda function in `.transform`, you are not using built-in vectorized Pandas operation and instead using slow non-optimized codes.  By directly using the [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) function, your codes become vectorized and run much faster.

### Result Comparison

2 column names generated by original and new codes:

```
df["value_lag1"] = df.groupby(['ID'])["value"].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1))

df["value_lag2"] = df.groupby(['ID'])["value"].shift(1)

df["value_lag1"].compare(df["value_lag2"])

# No difference shown by the compare function:

        self    other
index
```

### Performance Comparison

```
%%timeit
df["value_lag1"] = df.groupby(['ID'])["value"].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1))

36.6 s ± 768 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
df["value_lag1"] = df.groupby(['ID'])["value"].shift(1)

715 ms ± 64.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**36.6s vs 0.715s**:    Improved by **51x times faster**